# Should I formally use static_cast in C++ projects instead of C-style casts?

Tags: c++, casting

As title, should I always use `static_cast` for C++ project; if I just want to handle the conversion from `double` to `int` and the conversion from a base-pointer to a derived-pointer. Is my thought correct?

Thanks all

Comment: No, because `static_cast` doesn't do everything. Use the right cast for the job.

Comment: There are four named casts in C++. Use the appropriate one in each case. Do note that a C style cast can do a job that none of the four named casts can. But in general, try to *avoid casts*. A good strategy to avoid casts is to not throw away information about type in the first place.

Comment: If that was true then the other cast types would be redundant

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What can C cast do that others can't?

Comment: @NeilKirk: it can cast to an otherwise inaccessible base (refererence or pointer) with proper address adjustment (like `static_cast` would do if it could handle this case).

Answer (score 0):

Use `static_cast` for `double` to `int` conversions, but you probaby want `dynamic_cast` for base-pointer to derived-pointer.